# Remove TikTok videos from Google photos

Tags: google-photos, online-backup

TikTok downloads videos into the DCIM camera folder - the same folder that the default Camera app saves your own photos/videos in. It's an absurd choice by TikTok to store downloaded videos in your camera folder.

And since I have Google Photos automatically back up all my Camera photos/videos, it ends up backing up TikTok videos as well.

TikTok doesn't allow changing its default folder to save downloaded files in.

And Google Photos doesn't allow **not** syncing the default camera folder.

It seems I'm locked in with having to involuntarlity back up TikTok videos, should I chose to download them, to Google Photos.

Is there any way I can:

- Prevent Google Photos from backing up TikTok downloaded videos?
- Remove previously (or future) backed up  TikTok videos from Google Photos?

Comment: I think this question should be closed as off-topic because it is about mobile apps and a mobile device and should be asked on [android.se]. Perhaps if you are talking about a web app-based solution you could [edit] the question to refocus it and clarify the web apps portion of the question.

Comment: @Blindspots While the part about syncing doesn't seem to be on-topic here, it is on-topic to ask how to find and delete TikTok recordings from the Google Photos web app ([photos.google.com](https://photos.google.com)).

Comment: There is nothing in the question that signals a transition between mobile-only apps and the web app version of that particular mobile app, and your point was already explicitely acknowledged in my comment to the OP asking them to *"refocus it and clarify the web apps portion of the question"*

Answer (score 1):

When in the Google Photos app, you can search specifically for videos in a separate category within the Search screen. Once in there, you can find further filters at the top. One of them is "Screen Recordings". All of my downloaded TikToks were stored there, along with the few actual screen recordings I took.

While it's not a full wipe of only TikTok downloads, I found it to be a close enough solution.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to clarify if the solution is in the web app or the mobile application.